# Creating a Chrome web application with shell commands

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, google-chrome, hta

I would like to create a simple HTML based application which will be used offline. The application needs to be able to execute shell commands (in Windows) to perform various actions.

How can I create a web application for Google Chrome which is able to execute shell commands relative to its path?

I am after a Chrome equivalent to `hta` with `WScript.Shell` equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a google chrome extension, than  you can write [NPAPI plugin](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html) to call native programs. For a regular web page I don't think it is possible from javascript. Using java applet may help.

Comment: Cheers, is it possible to call native programs with arguments?

Comment: Yes, NPAPI plugins have unrestricted access to the local machine. Simply speaking, it is a native dll library, which you call from javascript code. Note, that you need to write the library too and it may be not so easy for those, who not very familiar with C / C++ programming and WinAPI.